# Jenkins Job Failure Due To Old TFS Workspace

Tags: jenkins, tfs, mapping, workspace

I have a jenkins job that is failing due the error:

An error occurred: The path XXXX is already mapped in workspace YYYY;ZZZ\ServiceAccount.

The service account that is being referenced is from the domain that the TFS server was recently migrated from.

I have tried various fixes to remove this workspace mapping:

1. Run "tfs workspace -delete "{workspace name};ZZZ\ServiceAccount" -noprompt -server:tfs server -login:YYY"
   This fails with the error message "ZZZ\ServiceAccount" is not a valid account. It is true that the account does not exist on the new domain.
2. Run "tf workspaces /remove:*" to remove all workspace caches. This completes.
3. Deleted the contents of "%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache".

Our TFS Server is running version 2013.

4. Tried using Team Foundation Sidekicks 2013. But this also fails to find any workspaces for "ZZZ\ServiceAccount".

I have tried on both the slave where the Jenkins job is run, and the Jenkins master.

Where might this workspace mapping be cached and how can I remove it now that the domain and user no longer exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the workaround provided by Jake Wallace in this [case](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33487?focusedCommentId=353886&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-353886):

> An easy workaround that has been used for several pipelines that have
> run into this issue is to rename the pipeline. Not ideal but can add a
> suffix or prefix to the pipeline until you run into the issue again.

In addition, after you clean all entries in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache\*.*`, did you restart the Jenkins agent and then rerun the build?